# Is there a watermark that i can edit

Tags: jquery, watermark

I am using this [plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/) and it works great but i cant edit the text ...if i click on it, it disappears. Is there an easy way to implement that or any other plugin that maybe able to help me

Comment: I don't get it. The very point of this plugin is to have the text disappear when you click on the input. Could you describe better what you're expecting? Sounds like you just want to pre-populate inputs with default values...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote a similar snippet that may be useful to you. It would use the html5 `placeholder` attribute if it were available to the browser, and would fall back if the browser didn't support it.

[Link to jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/partkyle/V2R9J/)

[Link to other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028846/clear-default-value/4028956#4028956)

**Edit :** I misunderstood your post, sorry.

[Try this example out](http://jsfiddle.net/partkyle/unXhU/).  It's not very complicated, but it is a small plugin that should get you started. Maybe you could give a little more information, since I don't know why you would want to do this other than to pre-populate the inputs with values.

Using @Tom's comment I rewrote [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwrjN/2/).  There are many ways to achieve this, assuming this is what you want.

Comment: Your javascript is almost unnecessary there. http://jsfiddle.net/WwrjN/ does the same with CSS only, except, it wont work in IE 6 and 7.

Comment: True, but he did ask for a plugin. I've edited your script to enable the functionality for virtually any browser (IE 6&7 don't like the ":focus" CSS selector)