# clear text field value when mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three text input fields, like [this on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24n7t/1/).

I put my code here also:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  value="age" size=30>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="text"  value="Name" size=30>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  value="your email" size=30>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
input{color:#CCC;}
```

js:

```
$('input').click(function() {

            $(this).attr('value', '');
            $(this).css('color','#000');

        }
    });
```

I would like the **mouse click** on each field will **clear the default value**, and when user input value, the **text color is black** instead of gray.

What I tried is showing on the jsfiddle link. But it does not work, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [clear default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028846/clear-default-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work on jsfiddle because you didn't choose to load jQuery (on the left sidebar).

Also, you have an unnecessary bracket (`}`). Remove that and it should work.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/24n7t/2/)'s a working example on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 5):

In HTML5, you could use `placeholder` for this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="age" size=30>
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/24n7t/13/

But it only works in modern browsers.

Comment: +1 for placeholder, though note that it is an HTML5 attribute (in case the OP wants compatibility with older browsers).

Comment: was this question tagged as html5?

Comment: @refhat; some times people didn't know about new attributes in WEB & may be that answer will be helpful for Leem

Comment: @sandeep this still feels like a misleading answer to me - if you present an alternative to the OP's requested technology, you need to say so. Also, some information about *which* browsers support it exactly would be nice

Comment: Agree with Pekka, Sandeep you could have mentioned that in a comment.

Comment: ... it's good info though, I didn't know this and I'm glad I found out about it.

Comment: Stands out much better as an answer! ;-) And it makes this fix-my-bug-question much more Q&A material, I think! As an aside: see [Is it our business to suggest alternative methods?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117221/is-it-our-business-to-suggest-alternative-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You have error in jquery code, 1 more curly brace

I remove it use below code

```
$('input').click(function() {

            $(this).attr('value', '');
            $(this).css('color','#000');

        });
```

and second thing you included jquery library??
if yes than ok and also include `document.ready` syntax

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error: you have an extra `}`

Answer (score 0):

Some possible improvements...

```
$('input[type=text], input[type=password]')   //leave submit buttons, etc alone
  .bind( 'focus', function() {                //focus is more accessible than click
                                              //a user can't change a field without it
      $(this)
         .attr('value', '')                   //more chaining = less searching
         .css('color','#000');
     })
  .bind( 'blur', function() {                 //supposing you want to revert back on blur...
      $(this)
         .css('color','#ccc');
     });
```